# Wordpress plugin class won't set filter

Tags: wordpress

im trying to rewrite my post content with a plugin. The filter works when i call it from outside of the plugin class, but i am not able to make it work from the class itself. Here's a stub of the code: http://pastie.org/2494050

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your `render_grid` method public explicitly. As far as I remember,it is required to do that for filter functions.

Answer (score 0):

there's no need in using reference `&$this` [check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Calling filters this manner works for me:

```
add_filter('content_save_pre', array($this, 'render_grid'));
```

Also I am curious why don't you pass `$content` argument to your filter function?

```
public function save($post_id) {
    ...
    add_filter('content_save_pre', array($this, 'render_grid'), 10, 1);
}
function render_grid($content) {
    ...
    return $grid_content;
}
```

and another [note from the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre):

> the filter function **must** return a string after it is finished
>   processing or the content will be empty

Hope this answer helps.